# Localization vs Navigation

Tags: ros, localization, navigation, ekf-localization, amcl

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am learning ROS for my first time, and I am confused about the difference between localization and navigation.  As I understand it, amcl is the package used for localization, but then the navigation stack is a separate package.  I am having a hard time seeing the difference between the two, because it seems the nav_stack is performing localization tasks; I do not see the need for localization.  Is it possible to run a robot only using the nav_stack with sensors and actuators; without using any sort of localization?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/239980/localization-vs-navigation/) by [Raisintoe](https://answers.ros.org/users/27360/raisintoe/) on ROS Answers with karma: 51 on 2016-07-20

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Broadly speaking, Navigation Stack of ROS involves the folllowings

1. Localization
2. Collision Avoidance
3. Trajectory Planning

Localization involves one question: Where is the robot now?  or where am I, keeping in mind that "here" is relative to some landmark.

---

Originally posted by [cagatay](https://answers.ros.org/users/2526/cagatay/) with karma: 1850 on 2016-07-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-07-21**:
And then navigation is *how do I get somewhere else* (preferably without hitting things along the way).

**Comment by [cagatay](https://answers.ros.org/users/2526/cagatay/) on 2016-07-21**:
also exploring and mapping the enviroment that robot is operating

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-07-21**:
I guess this could be subjective, but I'm not sure navigation includes all that. I can navigate quite well without making a map at the same time, provided I already have one, which is certainly possible.

**Comment by [cagatay](https://answers.ros.org/users/2526/cagatay/) on 2016-07-21**:
I am referring to nav_stack of ros

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-07-21**:
Ah ok, I understood your comment to be about the concept of navigation in general.

**Comment by [cagatay](https://answers.ros.org/users/2526/cagatay/) on 2016-07-21**:
I edited my response regarding to ROS, yeah it may be subjective but generally speaking, the navigation concept can be extended to involve mapping and exploration

**Comment by [Raisintoe](https://answers.ros.org/users/27360/raisintoe/) on 2016-07-22**:
Cagatay, thank you for the response.  So when talking about navigation, there are a number of packages I need to consider.  What are they? Or what are the main parts that make up navigation?  So far I have been reading about amcl for mapping, and the nav_stack.  Also tf is helpful.

**Comment by [cagatay](https://answers.ros.org/users/2526/cagatay/) on 2016-07-25**:
you can start with reading the tutorials here http://wiki.ros.org/navigation/Tutorials